# How can I fetch the number in a b tag through selenium-python?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm trying to get the number in all the `<b>` tags on this website. I want every single "qid" (question id) so I think I have to use `qids = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("b")`, and based on other questions I've found I also need to implement a for loop and then `print(qids.get_attribute("text"))` but my code can't even seem to find elements with the `<b>` since I keep on getting the NoSuchElementException. The appearance of the website leads me to believe the content I'm looking for is within an iframe but I'm not sure if that affects the functionality of my code.
[Here's a screencap of the website for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3RnU.png)
The html isn't of much use because the tag is its only defining trait:

```
<b>13570etc...</b>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you paste your DOM /HTML for accurate answers?

Comment: Do you mean like, the whole thing?

Comment: add relevant data only as you have pasted img which gives us  less idea about your problem.

Comment: Ok, will do. I'll post it here in the comments ASAP. By the way, sorry if I'm not very good at all this, I guess you could say I'm inexperienced and just getting into the hang of things on stack overflow and software development in general.

Comment: Thank you for your intent to help Amruta, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try searching by XPath:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//b")
```

Where `//` means "find all matching elements regardless of where they are in the document/current scope." Check out the XPath syntax [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) and mess around with a few different options.

Comment: Thank you so much Ryan!!! This solved my problem. 

To anyone who sees this and is having a similar problem: It turns out the iframe was affecting my code. I changed the "focus" for lack of a technical term, to the iframe with `driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))` and then used what was suggested by Ryan `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//b")` to locate all instances of the tag.
Again, thanks Ryan.

Comment: Glad I could help! And I'm sure future viewers will appreciate that you outlined the full solution.